# Juicer.io (Soc Media Feed) not loading only in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer-11, social-media

I used juicer.io (social media feed) in a website with the given embed code of their website. 
In every single browser and system it works, except for the Internet Explorer 11 (PAIN!!!!!)....
I'm guessing it must be some problem with javascript because what it shows is only the loading screen of the social media wall, but never the posts. (the loading screen shows up but never stops loading)
I'm really not good in Javascript, so I don't really know what to look for that IE 11 could have a problem with.
Any idea what the problem could be ? :(

```
  The embed code :
```

```
            <div class="social-feed">
               <script src="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <link href="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <ul class="juicer-feed" data-columns="4" data-feed-id="*********" data-per="4" data-truncate="120"  data-after="translateJuicer()"></ul>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function translateJuicer() {
                    jQuery('.j-paginate').text("Mehr"); 
                    jQuery('.j-read-more').text("Mehr");  
                }
            </script>      
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Try to check the browser console to see if there is any JavaScript errors or not. If there is any error than try to solve it may fix your issue. Other thing you need to make sure is your site is at least using jQuery version 1.7 If issue persist than you can also try to contact Juicer support via this link. https://www.juicer.io/contact